# Не получаю данные из module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

data.js

```
pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {

client.query('SELECT id, user_id, name  FROM public.chat;', function (err, 
 result) {
    if (err) console.log("error" + err.message);


    else {

        done();
        console.log(result.rows[0]);
              module.exports.res =  result.rows[0];
         }
        });

    });
```

app.js

```
var con = require('./db/connect');
console.log(con.res);
```

Выводит не

undefined

Дело с обратным вызовом, но ка реализовать не понимаю.

Comment: почитайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.js

```
var pool = require('./connect').pool;
var Promise = require('promise');


module.exports.SelMsg = function MsgSel() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.connect()
            .then(function (client) {
                client.query('SELECT text FROM public.message;')

                    .then(function (res) {
                        resolve(res);
                        client.release();
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                })

            })
```

app.js

```
var con = require('./db/data.js');
var users = await con.SelUser(); // использовал await что бы дождаться ответа.
```